# CefSharp ChromiumBrowser looses focus when opening file picker via <input type="file">

Tags: winforms, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

As said in the title, given I am visiting a page, that has a simple `<input type="file">` on and I open a file picker using that input, the main app (WinForms) looses focus (which is to be expected), however when I pick a file or cancel the file picker dialog, the main window regains a focus (noticable as a status bar color change) however the chromium component does not regain it. I have a JavaScript listener for keyboard input (keyboard shortcuts) on that page and they no longer work until I click on some random position inside chromium component.

I added a simple 'Activated' event listener to the form hosting the ChromiumBrowser component and inside it I am checking if ChromiumBrowser has a focus and in that particual scenario it is false.

```
mainForm.Activated += (s, a) => 
{
    if (mainForm.ChromeBrowser.IsBrowserInitialized)
    {
        var hasFocus = mainForm.ChromeBrowser.ContainsFocus; // hasFocus is false after file picker dialog is closed.

        var focus = mainForm.ChromeBrowser.Focus(); // returns false
    }
};
```

If I try to manually set the focus to the ChromiumBrowser component, it returns false (don't know why and have no idea how to figure that out).

The focus was normally regained after closing the file picker in the version 79.1.360 - we recently upgraded to 120.1.110 and noticed that issue.

Is there anything else I can try to regain focus on the proper component? I even tried simulating a mouse click but it does not help.

EDIT: at some other part of the application we already use the ChromeBrowser.Focus() method and there it returns  'true' however focus is still not on the component itself.

Comment: Have you tried to set the Form's `ActiveControl` to the instance of your browser?

Comment: @Jimi thank you for response. Yes, I have, same result.

Comment: You should also have a `[ChromiumWebBrowser].Activate()` method -- IIRC, there was a similar issue with WebView2. In that case, since the Control is just a container for the rendering surface, IIRC2 it was injected a JavaScript, to set the focus on an element of the page (the one that previously lost the focus - reported by an event listener) -- If this is a regression issue, you'll get more *focused* information when amaitland comes by

Comment: I don't believe it's a JS issue or that it can be solved by JS - I first tried setting the focus via Javascript (I though it was a web app underneath issue) but it's not. Also, since focus is regained when app is minimized and then back maximized, no JS is executed.

Comment: I said the opposite: a similar focus issue - in WebView2 - could be solved using JavaScript (injected client-side, for this purpose) -- Don't you have an `Activate()` method in your ChromeWebBrowser object? IIRC, that method is called to solve some other kind of focus issues, since `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` is used sometimes -- BTW, why do you have `MainForm.Activated` / `MainForm.ChromeBrowser` there? Do you have static / singleton objects + changed access modifiers? Why? Cross-thread stuff?

Comment: I see, I misunderstood. -- I do have .Activate() method but it does not make any difference-- Regarding the last part, MainForm is the name of the object and ChromeBrowser is a public property of the main form - nothing static, just maybe poorly named variables.

Comment: Yes, but you have then the instance of a Form there, so this is not the MainForm class, you're trying to focus a UI element from somewhere else. I'm saying this because, as mentioned before, in some cases - I assume to solve other issues related to focus changes - the windows of the container control class (IIRC), is created with the `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` style. So this could be a regression issue (or a bug). [amaitland](https://github.com/amaitland) is the maintainer and a SO user